# Chapter start gets pushed on following page (NOT the "openright/openany-problem")

Tags: page-breaking, chapters

It is hard to find answers to this question, as it sounds similar to the basic "How to start chapter on every page"-question. But this is different. Latex pushes the start of a chapter that contains a large figure, large minipage, large box, etc. on the next page and wrongly leaves an empty page. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV12,
openany,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\chapter{Chapter 1: All fine}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,5cm);
\chapter{Chapter 2: still ok}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,15cm);
\chapter{Chapter 3: I'm on the wrong page}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,21cm);
\end{document}
```

If you compile this you will see that chapter 1 and 2 are correctly placed at page 1 and 2, respectively, while chapter 3 gets pushed to page 4. I assume this is due to somehow on the even pages there is slightly more space than on the odd pages? Any hints on how I can force chapter 3 to start on page three would be great!
(This is for the appendix of a document where I want to place large figures (not floating) that just fit on the page.)

Thanks, Jochen

Comment: Welcome! It is probably because you don't have space for a 21cm high figure on the page, whereas you do have space for a 5cm or 15cm one.

Comment: Right, this is what I also think. But why do I have the space on the even page 4 where latex puts the box, but not on page 3? And how can I change it so that page 3 has the same space as page 4? Jochen

Comment: See my answer. Page 4 has no more space. But LaTeX knows not to produce indefinitely many empty pages. If starting a new page isn't enough, it won't keep starting more new pages. I give an example below to show this: if the initial problem occurs on page 4, chapter 4 ends up on page 5 and page 4 is empty instead.

Comment: I tried this code out of curiosity. Why am I only seeing the page heading on page 4? Is it because LaTex thinks it's the second page of chapter 3?

Comment: @GeoffPointer You should get the chapter title and rectangle on page 4. Page 3 should be almost empty.

Comment: @cfr I'm talking about the page header, not the chapter title. There is no page header on pages 1, 2 and 3, but there is on page 4.

Comment: @GeoffPointer That is normal: you don't have a header on a page with a chapter title.

Comment: @cfr Only in this case, because the third chapter title is being pushed onto another page you do see a header on a page with a chapter title, which is what I was guessing in the first place, but asked because I wanted to be sure. Thank you.

Comment: @GeoffPointer What I meant was, you are not supposed to. Besides, you asked why you did *not* get it on certain pages - not why you *did*.

Comment: @cfr So, the answer to: "Is it because LaTex thinks it's the second page of chapter 3?" is yes.

Comment: @GeoffPointer <shrug> If you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX will not allow a page break between the chapter title and the initial content of the chapter. When it finds that there is insufficient space on page 3, it therefore starts a new page.

You can see this in the console output:

```
chapter 3.
[3]
Overfull \vbox (1.59201pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[4] (./prawf.aux) )
```

You can see that there is a bad box here: an overly full `\vbox` which is just a little too high for the page (`1.59201pt` too high). Hence, LaTeX starts page 4. If there is a little less stuff to fit, the problem vanishes

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV12,
openany,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\chapter{Chapter 1: All fine}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,5cm);
\chapter{Chapter 2: still ok}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,15cm);
\chapter{Chapter 3: I'm on the wrong page}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,20cm);
\end{document}
```

Note that there isn't room on page 4 for the 21cm high rectangle either, but LaTeX cannot do more than give the box a new page. It does not look back and realise that this box is the first thing on page 3 - it just tries pushing to a new page once and once only. This is just as well as it would otherwise produce indefinitely many empty pages, since it would keep pushing content to the next page and the next *ad infinitum*.

To see that it is not a question of different amounts of space on odd and even pages, note that

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV12,
openany,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\chapter{Chapter 1: All fine}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,5cm);
\chapter{Chapter 2: still ok}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,15cm);
\chapter{Chapter 3: I'm on the wrong page}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,20cm);
\chapter{Chapter 4: I'm on the wrong page}
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,21cm);
\end{document}
```

produces *five* pages, with page *four* blank and a complaint about an overly full `\vbox` which is, again, just as much too high as it was on page 3.

It is just that LaTeX knows to only try the start-a-new-page strategy once. After that, it will try its best and typeset the box even though there is not room for it.

## EDIT

In response to questions raised in comments, there are a couple of ways to work around the issue.

Ideally, of course, things are managed so that the content fits the space. This can be done by making the page bigger or by making the content smaller. For example

```
\resizebox{!}{20.5cm}{\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,21cm);}
```

can be used to resize the content to height 20.5cm, scaling the width proportionately.

Another possibility is to lie. If TeX is told the content fits, it will believe you. Of course, this will not mean the content really fits and you won't get any warnings that it doesn't. So you need to check the output carefully with this option! There are various ways to do this. Here's one (not necessarily the best):

```
\chapter{Chapter 4: I'm on the wrong page}
\vfill\centering\makebox(0,0){\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (10cm,21cm);}\vfill
```

This will not work well if the content is much too large as it is centring the content vertically on the page, which means it uses a bit of the space under the chapter heading, as well as a bit of the space from the foot of the page. But for just-slightly-too-big content, that is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for the elaborate answer on how the problem occurs, this I understand now. The main goal (preventing the empty page) however is still unachieved IF I want to keep the size of the box/figures. Is is possible to tell latex to output the (too large) box immediately without trying to push the output on an new page?It seems to me to be a bug of latex to push the output from one empty page to another empty page (or to "not look back" as you call it).

I guess I will try to change the margins for this one page without changing the position of the page numbering, then it should work.

Comment: You have to remember that the system was designed when computer resources were rather slimmer than they are today. Some of the things TeX fails to do are explained by the original need to use limited resources to best effect.

Comment: Anyway, the obvious solution is to ensure the content does fit on the page. Is that an option? You could scale it, for example, to fit the available space. Otherwise, it is always possible to lie to TeX and tell it that a box has certain dimensions, even though it doesn't. TeX is very trusting and will take you at your word. Of course, the content will not actually fit. TeX will just think it does.

Comment: From the historic perspective with limited resources it is understandable. But nowadays one could think about including this feature (leave out uselessly included empty page). And yes, you are right, having the correctly sized image would be the best option. Anyway could you tell me how to lie to latex about the box size? My attempt with the geometry-package unfortunately does shift the pagenumbering.

Comment: Please see edited answer above.

Comment: cfr, thank you so much! It worked out perfectly when simply enclosing the content of the page in \makebox(0,0)[tl]{...}. With this it is still nicely aligned. I will definitely remember the makebox-command. Again, thank you for your time, now I can finally go to sleep (it's 5:15am here in Germany right now).

Comment: couldn't you also use `\enlargethispage` immediately after the `\chapter` line?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you think that would be preferable?

Comment: @cfr -- i don't know about "preferable", but (being inherently lazy) it's what i'd try first.  the solution you suggested is probably more powerful and more susceptible to variation when circumstances conspire against logic.